# Using gdb to find exactly where the error occurs (SPARC assembly)

Tags: assembly, gdb, sparc

I'm trying to use gdb to debug my assembly subroutine, but was having trouble trying to determine where exactly the program reaches a segfault.

I run it until it reaches the segfault, then use the 'where' command, which gives me this:

```
0x00010e40 in swapChars()
```

Is there a way for me to figure out exactly what line the segfault occurred at in my subroutine?

Comment: `x/i $pc` will show the current instruction. You can also ask for more context if needed, see the help. You don't need debug info for this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to figure out exactly what line the segfault occurred at in my subroutine?

Yes: you need to compile your program with debugging info (the output you provided shows that you likely haven't).

Usually that's as simple as adding `-g` to `CFLAGS`.

Sometimes programs lack debug info because there is a stray `-s` (strip debug info) flag on the link line.

Answer (score 0):

In gdb, use the command 'layout asm' and it will switch to a view of the assembly code. Then you should be able to see exactly which instruction caused the fault.